# How can I add extra properties to document metadata field types in Liferay 6.1?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portal, expando

I'm new to Liferay and I have the following situation:

I would like to add **extra properties** to document metadata field types in Liferay 6.1.20.

For example, I would like to add property '**readonly**' to select boxes (see image), as it is a user requirement to show some controls disabled.

Should I use the Expando functionality, a jsp override hook or another approach?

[image: Liferay document metadata field type properties]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Expando functionality, a jsp override hook are a good approach.But using Expando you cannot create it as mandatory field.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. Could you please elaborate a little bit more on this? On which class should I use Expando? And on which jsp or html snippet should I add the readonly functionality for the html controls?